# Add Admin order notes sent to customer in WooCommerce My Account Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, account

Based on [WooCommerce admin orders list custom column with order notes sent to customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205612/woocommerce-admin-orders-list-custom-column-with-order-notes-sent-to-customer) answer code, I have tried unsuccessfully to add the following code to make a new column in the WooCommerce My Account Orders list where I've changed `manage_edit-shop_order_columns` to `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns` hook like:

```
// Add custom column on admin orders list page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'add_order_notes_column' );
function add_order_notes_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['order_notes'] = 'Order Notes';
    return $columns;
}

// CSS styles
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
function add_order_notes_column_style() {
    $css = '.post-type-shop_order table.widefat.fixed { table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }';
    $css .= 'table.wp-list-table .column-order_notes { min-width: 280px; text-align: left; }';
    $css .= '.column-order_notes ul { margin: 0 0 0 18px; list-style-type: disc; }';
    // $css .= '.order_customer_note { color: #ee0000; }'; // red
    // $css .= '.order_private_note { color: #0000ee; }'; // blue
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
}

// Admin orders list custom column displayed content
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'add_order_notes_content' );
function add_order_notes_content( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if( 'order_notes' !== $column )
        return;

    $order = is_a($the_order, 'WC_Order') ? $the_order : wc_get_order( $post->ID );

    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'order_by' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );

    if( ! empty($notes) ) {
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach( $notes as $note ) {
            if( $note->customer_note && 'system' !== $note->added_by ) {
                echo '<li class="order_customer_note">' . sprintf( __('%s by %s <br> %s:'),
                    date_i18n( 'm/d/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) ),
                    $note->added_by,
                    $note->content
                ) . '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

I want the content of this column to be the same, but I want the title to say "Download".

Updated: Here is a screenshot where I want the column to go:

[image: screenshot of columns]

Comment: can you give a screenshot of where exactly you want it?

Comment: I tried, but I'm not sure I did it right. I want it at the end after total. I hid Actions on my list.

Comment: so you want `Order Notes` to `Download`?

Comment: I plan to use a "note to customer" to provide them with a URL. This will be a dropbox link to download their file. Unless there is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: so you want `Order Notes` to `note to customer`?

Comment: I'd like the customer to see "Download" on their end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code… To display the customer order notes sent by admin in My account orders as a new column, use the following instead:

```
// Add custom column on admin orders list page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'add_myaccount_admin_order_notes_column' );
function add_myaccount_admin_order_notes_column( $columns ) {
    $column_actions = $columns['order-actions'];
    unset($columns['order-actions']);

    $columns['admin-notes'] = __('Admin Notes', 'woocommerce');
    $columns['order-actions'] = $column_actions;

    return $columns;
}

// CSS styles
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myaccount_admin_order_notes_inline_style', 100 );
function myaccount_admin_order_notes_inline_style() {
    if( is_account_page() && is_wc_endpoint_url('orders') ) :
    ?><style>ul.order-note-item {list-style:none; margin:0;} ul.order-note-item > li { margin:0 0 6px;}</style><?php
    endif;
}

// Admin orders list custom column displayed content
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_admin-notes', 'add_myaccount_admin_order_notes_content' );
function add_myaccount_admin_order_notes_content( $order ) {
    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'order_by' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );

    if( ! empty($notes) ) {
        $output = [];

        foreach( $notes as $note ) {
            if( $note->customer_note && 'system' !== $note->added_by ) {
                $output[] = sprintf( __('%s <br> %s'),
                    date_i18n( 'm/d/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) ),
                    $note->content
                );
            }
        }
        echo '<ul class="order-note-item"><li>'. implode('</li><li>', $output) .'</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer that didn't confuse me. Worked perfectly!