# Display private and customer admin notes in a custom column on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

Based on the answer by LoicTheAzec on [Add Admin order notes sent to customer in WooCommerce My Account Orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269652/add-admin-order-notes-sent-to-customer-in-woocommerce-my-account-orders-list/67272375#67272375)

This is my attempt to display private and customer admin notes in a custom column on WooCommerce admin orders list, wrapped in `<details>` and `<summary>` tags.

```php
// Add custom column on admin orders list page
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_notes_column' );
function add_order_notes_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['order_notes'] = 'Order Notes';
    return $columns;
}

// CSS styles
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
function add_order_notes_column_style() {
    $css = '.post-type-shop_order table.widefat.fixed { table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }';
    $css .= 'table.wp-list-table .column-order_notes { min-width: 280px; text-align: left; }';
    $css .= '.column-order_notes ul { margin: 0 0 0 18px; list-style-type: disc; }';
    $css .= '.order_customer_note { color: #ee0000; }'; // red
    $css .= '.order_private_note { color: #0000ee; }'; // blue
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
}

// Admin orders list custom column displayed content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_order_notes_content' );
function add_order_notes_content( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if( 'order_notes' !== $column )
        return;

    $order = is_a($the_order, 'WC_Order') ? $the_order : wc_get_order( $post->ID );

    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'order_by' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );

    if( ! empty($notes) ) {
        echo '<details><summary>Click to read notes</summary><ul>';

        foreach( $notes as $note ) {
            if( $note->customer_note && 'system' !== $note->added_by ) {
                echo '<li class="order_customer_note">' . sprintf( __('%s by %s <br> %s:'),
                    date_i18n( 'm/d/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) ),
                    $note->added_by,
                    $note->content
                ) . '</li>';
            }

if( $note->private_note ) {
                echo '<li class="order_private_note">' . sprintf( __('%s by %s <br> %s:'),
                    date_i18n( 'm/d/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) ),
                    $note->added_by,
                    $note->content
                ) . '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></details>';
    }
}
```

---

However, while the customer notes are displayed, this is not the case for the private notes. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$note->private_note` does not exist.
- The use of global variables is also not necessary for your question.

So to display both customer notes and private admin notes you can use:

```php
// Add a Header
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    // Add new column
    $columns['order_notes'] = __( 'Order notes', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns', 10, 1 );

// Populate the Column
function action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'order_notes' ) {
        // Get order notes
        $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
            'order_id' => $post_id,
            'order_by' => 'date_created',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ));
        
        // Output when NOT empty 
        if ( ! empty( $notes ) ) {
            echo '<a href="#"><details><summary>Click to read notes</summary><ul>';

            // Loop trough notes
            foreach( $notes as $note ) {
                // NOT added by system
                if ( $note->added_by !== 'system' ) {
                    
                    // Customer note OR private note
                    $note->customer_note ? $class = 'order_customer_note' : $class = 'order_private_note';
                    
                    echo '<li class="' . $class . '">' . sprintf( __('%s <br> %s'),
                        date_i18n( 'm/d/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) ),
                        $note->content
                    )  . '</li>';
                }
            }
            
            echo '</ul></details></a>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );

// CSS styles
function add_order_notes_column_style() {
    $css = '.post-type-shop_order table.widefat.fixed { table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }';
    $css .= 'table.wp-list-table .column-order_notes { min-width: 280px; text-align: left; }';
    $css .= '.column-order_notes ul { margin: 0 0 0 18px; list-style-type: disc; }';
    $css .= '.order_customer_note { color: #ee0000; }'; // red
    $css .= '.order_private_note { color: #0000ee; }'; // blue
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
```